# Tensorflow: What's wrong in my .pb file ? How do I make it work?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to use my model to classify image , and the model is .pb file .Now here is some problem . The classify code is here:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PIL import Image
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import re
import os

model_dir = '/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/tfrecords/try1/'
image_dir = '/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/test_abc/19.jpg'
class NodeLookup(object):
    def __init__(self,
                 label_lookup_path=None,
                 uid_lookup_path=None):
        if not label_lookup_path:
            label_lookup_path = os.path.join(
                model_dir, 'imagenet_2012_challenge_label_map_proto.pbtxt')
        if not uid_lookup_path:
            uid_lookup_path = os.path.join(
                model_dir, 'alex_number.txt')
        self.node_lookup = self.load(label_lookup_path, uid_lookup_path)

    def load(self, label_lookup_path, uid_lookup_path):
        if not tf.gfile.Exists(uid_lookup_path):
            tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', uid_lookup_path)
        if not tf.gfile.Exists(label_lookup_path):
            tf.logging.fatal('File does not exist %s', label_lookup_path)
        proto_as_ascii_lines = tf.gfile.GFile(uid_lookup_path).readlines()
        uid_to_human = {}
        p = re.compile(r'[n\d]*[ \S,]*')
        for line in proto_as_ascii_lines:
            parsed_items = p.findall(line)
            uid = parsed_items[0]
            human_string = parsed_items[2]
            uid_to_human[uid] = human_string
        node_id_to_uid = {}
        proto_as_ascii = tf.gfile.GFile(label_lookup_path).readlines()
        for line in proto_as_ascii:
            if line.startswith('  target_class:'):
                target_class = int(line.split(': ')[1])
            if line.startswith('  target_class_string:'):
                target_class_string = line.split(': ')[1]
                node_id_to_uid[target_class] = target_class_string[1:-2]
        node_id_to_name = {}
        for key, val in node_id_to_uid.items():
            if val not in uid_to_human:
                tf.logging.fatal('Failed to locate: %s', val)
            name = uid_to_human[val]
            node_id_to_name[key] = name    
        return node_id_to_name    
    def id_to_string(self, node_id):
        if node_id not in self.node_lookup:
            return ''
        return self.node_lookup[node_id]
def create_graph():
    with tf.gfile.FastGFile(os.path.join(
            model_dir, 'alex_model22.pb'), 'rb') as f:
        graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
        graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
        tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
def get_one_image():
    image = Image.open(image_dir)
    #plt.imshow(image)
    image = image.resize([56, 56])    
    image = np.array(image)
    return image    
image_array=get_one_image()  
image = tf.cast(image_array, tf.float32)
image_1 = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image) 
image_2 = tf.reshape(image_1, [1, 56, 56, 3])

create_graph()    
sess = tf.Session()  
softmax_tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('softmax:0')   
predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'x-input': image_array})   
predictions = np.squeeze(predictions)

node_lookup = NodeLookup()
top_5 = predictions.argsort()[-5:][::-1]
for node_id in top_5:
    human_string = node_lookup.id_to_string(node_id)
    score = predictions[node_id]
    print('%s (score = %.5f)' % (human_string, score))   
sess.close()
```

Now I get error like this :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/tfrecords/try1/Alex_Read_pb.py", line 107, in <module>
    predictions = sess.run(softmax_tensor, {'x-input': image_array})
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/home/vrview/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 922, in _run
    + e.args[0])
TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: The name 'x-input' refers to an Operation, not a Tensor. Tensor names must be of the form "<op_name>:<output_index>".
```

Even though I know the error,but I don't know how to fix it .Here I will give my code which to create .pb file . I think something should change in this .

```
# coding=utf-8
from  color_1 import read_and_decode, get_batch, get_test_batch
from tensorflow.python.framework import graph_util
import tensorflow as tf

batch_size = 128
TRAIN_STEPS = 10000
crop_size = 56
REGULARAZTION_RATE=0.0001
MODEL_SAVE_PATH = "/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/tfrecords/try1/"
MODEL_NAME = "model.ckpt"   
def inference(input_tensor,train,regularizer):
    with tf.name_scope('conv1') as scope:
        kernel=tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([11,11,3,96],dtype=tf.float32,stddev=1e-1),name='weights1')
        conv=tf.nn.conv2d(input_tensor,kernel,[1,4,4,1],padding='SAME',name='con1')
        biases=tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.0,shape=[96],dtype=tf.float32),trainable=True,name='biases1')
        bias=tf.nn.bias_add(conv,biases)
        conv1=tf.nn.relu(bias,name=scope)
        lrn1=tf.nn.lrn(conv1,4,bias=1.0,alpha=0.001/9,beta=0.75,name='lrn1')
        pool1=tf.nn.max_pool(lrn1,ksize=[1,3,3,1],strides=[1,2,2,1],padding='VALID',name='pool1')

    with tf.name_scope('conv2') as scope:
        ......
        ......
    with tf.name_scope('conv3') as scope:
        ......
        ......
    with tf.name_scope('conv4') as scope:
        ......
        ......
    with tf.name_scope('conv5') as scope:
        .......

    pool_shape=pool5.get_shape().as_list()
    nodes=pool_shape[1]*pool_shape[2]*pool_shape[3]
    reshaped=tf.reshape(pool5,[pool_shape[0],nodes])

    with tf.variable_scope('layer6-fc1'):
        fc1_weights=tf.get_variable("weight6",[nodes,4096],initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.1))
        if regularizer !=None:
            tf.add_to_collection('losses1',regularizer(fc1_weights))
        fc1_biases=tf.get_variable("biases6",[4096],initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(0.1))

        fc1=tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(reshaped,fc1_weights)+fc1_biases)
        if train:fc1=tf.nn.dropout(fc1,0.5)

    with tf.variable_scope('layer7-fc2'):
       ......
       ......
    with tf.variable_scope('layer8-fc3'):
        ......
        ......
        logit=tf.matmul(fc2,fc3_weights)+fc3_biases
    return logit
def train(batch_x, batch_y):
    image_holder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 56, 56, 3], name='x-input')
    label_holder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size], name='y-input')

    regularizer = tf.contrib.layers.l2_regularizer(REGULARAZTION_RATE)
    y = inference(image_holder, train,regularizer)
    global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)    
    def loss(logits, labels):
        labels = tf.cast(labels, tf.int64)
        y_conv = tf.nn.softmax(y, name='softmax')
        cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            logits=logits, labels=labels, name='cross_entropy_per_example')

        cross_entropy_mean = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy, name='cross_entropy')
        tf.add_to_collection('losses', cross_entropy_mean)
        return tf.add_n(tf.get_collection('losses'), name='total_loss')
    loss = loss(y, label_holder)
    train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3).minimize(loss)
    saver = tf.train.Saver(max_to_keep=30)
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(init)
        coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
        threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)   
        f=open('/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/tfrecords/try1/loss.txt','w')
        graph_def=tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()
        for i in range(TRAIN_STEPS):
            image_batch, label_batch = sess.run([batch_x, batch_y])
            _, loss_value, step = sess.run([train_op, loss, global_step], feed_dict={image_holder: image_batch,                                                                                      label_holder: label_batch})
            if i % 100 == 0:
                format_str = ('After %d step,loss on training batch is: %g')
                print (format_str % (i, loss_value))
            f.write(str(i+1) +', loss_value:'+ str(loss_value) + '\n')
        output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, graph_def,['softmax','x-input'])
        with tf.gfile.GFile("/home/vrview/tensorflow/example/char/tfrecords/try1/alex_model22.pb",
                            "wb") as f:
            f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
            f.close()    
        coord.request_stop()
        coord.join(threads) 
def main(argv=None):
    image, label = read_and_decode('train.tfrecords')
    batch_image, batch_label = get_batch(image, label, batch_size, crop_size)   
    train(batch_image, batch_label)    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.run()
```

Maybe I should not save the point 'x-input' . but I don't know what point should to save .Does anybody know how to solve this ? thank you very much.
[image]
the pic is graph of my code

Comment: What happens when you use image holder instead of x-input. I don't think you can just pass the name like that in the feed-dict. You've only named it x-input but it looks like it's assigned to image_holder.

Comment: x-input is just a name of image_holder , and in my saved .pb file , I want to input a picture to get it's class , but I  don't know how to modification the code to save a right .pb . The error is in image input . Do you know how to modification my code and get a right .pb file and classify my image?

Comment: What happens when you load your graph into Tensorboard? Could you post that on here? TO make sure your graph is how it should be. The error appears to be that you're trying to feed into something that can't be fed into. Did you try my suggested modification?

Comment: It seems difficult to load graph into tensorboard ,I am not good in this . and the net I omit is AlexNet . The first code which I load pb file is the code that I get from web ,and I just do a little change . the web is :" http://www.cnblogs.com/denny402/p/6942580.html " I am not sure whether you can open it ...

Comment: Did you try my suggestion above? I can't help until you've tried it.

Comment: I already add the graph , can you see it ?

Comment: 'x-input' is the name of the tensor. You should get that tensor by 'get_tensor_by_name('x-input:0') and pass that tensor in your feed_dict.

Comment: ok,I will try this . thank you very much

Comment: Yes the above should also work. Usually if you assign a placeholder by var_name=tf.Placeholder(...) you should be able to pass it to feed_dict by using var_name/ That's how my code is all set up. But i think there are some nuances with this so vijay m's solution is the "proper" way to try and resolve your problem! Good luck!

Comment: e~~~~I am still confused~I just want to input one image with ' x-input '

Comment: You just need to feed "x_input:0" instead of "x_input" AFAICT